# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Playlist' and 'Playlist' getting this error

Tags: django

```
def home(request):

    context = {
        '': Playlist.objects.all()
    } 

    query = ""
    if request.GET:
        query = request.GET['q']
        context['query'] = str(query)

    playlists = sorted(get_video_queryset(query))
    context['playlists']=playlists

    return render(request, "video/home.html", context)
```

i am trying to make a search bar all was working fine then I started working on a post creating page, then it just occured as shown

Comment: `get_video_queryset` returns a set of `Playlist` objects. But since you can not *order* two `Playlist`, the `sorted(..)` makes not much sense.

Comment: Can you share the details of the `get_video_queryset`, the `Playlist` model and also specify how you want to *order* the `Playlist`s.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted` function takes items from given iterable and makes comparisons between them. Such a comparison might be `>` or `<` (as in your case).

I guess that `get_video_queryset` returns an iterable of `Playlist` objects and those objects do not support comparisons - that's why you get an error saying that comparison is not possible.

You have 3 possibilities:

1. Use ORM's `order_by()` method to sort by specific model field. Example:

   ```
   # Assuming that playlist has a name and you want to sort by it
   playlists = get_video_queryset(query).order_by('name')
   ```

   You can read more about ordering [in Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).
   This is the best solution if your are working on a queryset, because you ordering would be done in one query, by a database itself.
2. Specify `key=` parameter for `sorted` function. `key` is a function which takes item from sorted list as a parameter and should return value which will be used in comparisons. Read more about it [in Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)
3. Implement [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__) in your `Playlist` class so that objects of that class can be compared directly.

First solution seems the best for me, because it's the cleanest and fastest one **if `get_video_queryet` returns a queryset**.

Third option seems the worst, because you add a lot of code to your models and it's much more complicated than first 2 methods.

Comment: I got **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'**

Comment: That's because `order_by` must be called on a queryset, not on a list. Make sure your call it on QuerySet